# Issue while Integrating Finder Sync in Cocoa using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, findersync

I am trying to integrate Finder Sync Extension in my Cocoa Application to show badge in files and folders. But i faced some query:

1) Problem of to run the application means i want to run extension using my host application. Refer the below screen shots of that:

[image]

See the run pop-up menu, If i run app through FinderSyncExtension then it is added to Extension in System Preference but when i run my app through my host app like see blue menu item then it won't create extension.

2) FinderSync.m class is called only first time then it won't call so what is the issue of that?

Please give me brief idea related to integrate the FinderSync Extension.
And I refered the Apple official document of [FinderSync.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html)

Any help is appreciated..!

Comment: Post your code. Also, the very first paragraph of the docs you referred to says, "Unlike most extension points, Finder Sync does not add features to a host app. Instead, it lets you modify the behavior of the Finder itself." So what do you mean "when I run my app through my containing app"?

Answer (score 0):

1.On developing you can run FinderSync extension by selecting "FinderSyncExt" from    product-->Scheme. In my knowledge there is no direct connection between containing app and extension.

2. To stop your running Extension use "Stop" option from Product instead of button given to stop running application.On running a extension it initialise two process so to stop you have to press "Stop" twice(from product).

   And before you run Extension in Xcode make sure that your extension is unchecked from extensions list(System preference--> Extensions).

Hope it will help you.